# using Highlighted content web part which shows documents from "All sites in the hub" is not showing any documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, hub-site

I create the following 4 SharePoint Online sites as follow:-

1. MainGroup site and i registered it as Hub.
2. Finance site and i registered it as Hub + i defined the MainGroup as the parent hub.
3. Operations site and i registered it as Hub + + i defined the MainGroup as the parent hub.
4. Sales site and i registered it as Hub + + i defined the MainGroup as the parent hub.

now inside the MainGroup site home page >> i added a highlighted content web part >> and i defined to show Documents from "All Sites in the hub', as follow:-

[image]

but nothing were shown as follow:-

[image]

any advice? is the issue that i have sites defined as hubs and at the same time i am linking them to a parent hub? or it is a time issue? keeping in mind that i created the sites before 2 hours and i link them together after that.. and i have added around 100 documents all over the 4 sites..

Any advice please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sites-web-part-not-showing-all-sites-in-hub/m-p/3074092

There might be settings in the hub site that are affecting the visibility of the associated sites. Can you check the hub site settings to ensure that they are configured correctly?

Comment: what is the relation between the issue i mentioned and the link you provided?

Answer (score 0):

If you use another "Source" filter to filter these files, can it work fine? You may can try to replace "All Sites in the hub" with "This site". Check if the new Highlight Content web part can display the correct content?

If everything is fine with a different filter, it means it's a timing issue, please be patient and feel free to contact me if you have any other questions.

Comment: i tried selected sites (where i manually selected the Finance, Sales & operation)and it showed the documents correctly

Comment: Also all sites worked.. so not sure if the issue is with the option "All Sites in the hub".. could be an issue on sharepoint side?